# Creating Vector Attribute Field with Raster Value in QGIS

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-3, drape

I want to create a new attribute field contains data coming from a raster in a vector file. I tried the GRASS v.drape tool but the analysis did not create any new field in shapefile. Also, I tried the drape tool in QGIS and the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THere are two tools to query a raster and upload values to a vector attribute table.

1. If your vector is a points layer, then `v.what.rast` does that. You need to create the target attribute column in advance, with `v.db.addcolumn`.
2. If your vector contains lines or polygons, and you want to calculate "zonal statistics", then use `v.rast.stats`. This module creates several new attribute columns with average, maximum, minimum, standard deviation, etc. These columns are named with a "prefix" that you specify.

If you post some further details about your needs, your OS, etc, then a more detailed answer will be possible.

**TIP**: Don't forget to set your computational region to match the vector extent at the start. See `g.region` to understand how.

**Here's the procedure.** I have a roads line vector and a dem raster. First I show the existing columns in the roads attrib table before v.rast.stats:

```
micha@TP480:~$ v.info -c roads
Data element 'vector/roads' was found in more mapsets (also found in
<PERMANENT>)
Using <roads@Har_Hanegev>...
Displaying column types/names for database connection of layer <1>:
INTEGER|cat
INTEGER|gid
INTEGER|id
INTEGER|length
CHARACTER|name
CHARACTER|type
CHARACTER|use
CHARACTER|yishuv
```

Set the region

```
micha@TP480:~$ g.region -p vect=roads2
```

Now run v.rast.stats

```
micha@TP480:~$ v.rast.stats roads2 rast=dem_4m column_prefix=elev
WARNING: No areas selected from vector map <roads2>
WARNING: Not all vector categories converted to raster. Converted 147 of
         312.
Processing input data (147 categories)...
 100%
Updating the database ...
```

and here are the new attrib columns:

```
micha@TP480:~$ v.info -c roads2
Displaying column types/names for database connection of layer <1>:
INTEGER|cat
INTEGER|gid
INTEGER|id
INTEGER|length
CHARACTER|name
CHARACTER|type
CHARACTER|use
CHARACTER|yishuv
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_number
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_null_cells
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_minimum
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_maximum
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_range
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_average
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_stddev
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_variance
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_coeff_var
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_sum
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_first_quartile
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_median
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_third_quartile
DOUBLE PRECISION|elev_percentile_90
```

a small sample of the results:

```
micha@TP480:~$ v.db.select roads2 columns=elev_minimum,elev_maximum,elev_average,elev_stddev | head
elev_minimum|elev_maximum|elev_average|elev_stddev
-378.044708251953|-110.445526123047|-306.623860067546|81.2172675415943
-372.899230957031|-338.318267822266|-355.503255666097|8.52284278526592
-217.204177856445|-216.291137695312|-216.782756260463|0.324664221025042
-159.378814697266|-152.474395751953|-156.435197845877|1.78710129652147
-159.060150146484|-122.469970703125|-146.012489771125|11.1211311595026
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using a line vector type. v.rast.stats works with just polygons and creates points. I also tried "add raster values to features" tool of SAGA but it works with using interpolation. I try to find a tool like "Add Surface Information" tool of ArcMap. Also, I am using GRASS 7.6.0.

Comment: No, v.rast.stats works on line vectors as well. It calculates **for each line feature** several univariate statistics: average, minimum, maximum, stddev, etc. Did you expect something else?

Comment: I am trying to obtain these statistics in input line vector attribute table.

Comment: I added to my answer an example of a full workflow to get raster values into a line vector attribute table. After your read the manual pages for each of the GRASS modules, the procedure should become clear.

Comment: It is worked. Thank you so much for your support.